# Has the following algebraic structure been studied before

Tags: abstract-algebra, universal-algebra

I have recently been thinking about the following mathematical structure.  I am wondering if this structure has been studied before or if it is new (I doubt it as it seems a fairly obvious structure to consider)

Let $A$ be a set.  Let $\mathscr{A}$, be the set consisting of elements of the form $(a_1,a_2,...,a_n)$, where $n$ is a natural number or infinity, where $a_i \in A$.  (Sorry this is worded badly),  I means that the elements of $\mathscr{A}$ are finiite or infinite sequences of elements in $A$.

We define an interaction, $\times$, to be a function $C \rightarrow \mathscr{A}$ where $C$ is a subset of $\mathscr{A}$

-

Is there a name for this structure?  The reason I think this structure is worth studying is because other algebraic structures, such as groups, rings and modules over a ring can be considered to be a particular type of the above structure.

Comment: There's not much to go on - there are no algebraic properties given here, for example.

Comment: Could you explain how the "usual" structures are special cases of this?

Comment: As long as you do not define your "function" $\times$ there is nothing sensible about your question ... Do you have examples?

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are asking about is known as [universal algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_algebra). There is even a tag for it here on stackexchange.